# Is there a way to add a gradient to scaffoldBackgroundColor in Theme Data?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm implementing Dark Mode in my Flutter App. My original light mode had a decoration box to produce a Gradient, see below

```
decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          colors: [Color(0xffff8a93), Color(0xffffbf81)])),
```

Is there a way to add a gradient code to my light theme in ThemeData? primaryColor is my background

```
 static final lightTheme = ThemeData(
    primaryColor: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        appBarTheme:
            const AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.light, color: Colors.white,),
        inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        canvasColor: Color(0xff3a4759),
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.red.shade200, opacity: 0.8),
      );
}
```

Comment: Should it be with theme data? I have another way to reach it without using theme data that's why I asked you this

Comment: What's the other way to reach it?

Dark Mode: Colors.Grey
Light Mode: Gradient